# why absolute path omits http protocol?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

I know it's a dumb question but I can't find the answer on google.

I want to explicitly use `<link href="https://example.com/xyz" rel="canonical" />` but somehow the browser always shows `<link href="//example.com/xyz" rel="canonical" />` without the https protocol. **For canonical, I must use the path with https protocol.**,

other content like

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com/xyz">
```

still shows the correct path.

not sure if IIS has a hold on this. Anyone has any ideas ?

Comment: Am not sure why you think it is the browser that does this. It is not the browsers that creates the code, it just parse the one it gets from the server. Instead show how the server side part looks like, as I am sure that's where the issue lies.

Comment: Use a tool like Fiddler to capture the packets on the wire. That should tell who give the text.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Can you give some more context of how you write the `link` tag? Is this inside a Razor view? Do you dynamically create the URL in some way? Can you check if that dynamic creation produces correct absolute URLs?

Comment: @LGSon I don’t see why you interpret that OP thinks the browser does this. Since this is also tagged with ASP.NET Core, I would highly assume that OP is fully aware that this would be caused by the server…

Comment: @poke I interpreted it like that as OP wrote, in a comment below, _"I just can't force the browser stop omitting https,..."_.

Answer (score 0):

When using absolute path, current protocol is used.

Comment: thanks, but maybe you dont understand my question. I just can't force the browser stop omitting https, and for SEO canonical, link must shows https, not just // otherwise Google will complain.